# How can I print image field inside <img src=""> inside my custom views-view-fields.tpl.php

Tags: drupal

I have a view for news content type
I overrige the view's template grid style output
In Row style output:views-view-fields.tpl.php overriding every thing seems ok except image field!
I print tilte and description and every other thing using  print 
     `$fields['fieldname']->content;

but  print $fields['field_teamimage']->content; " class="img-respo" alt="team img 1">
displaying nothing!

How can I print image field inside Only local images are allowed. inside my custom views-view-fields.tpl.php
I spent all my day trying and searching without a result
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to override filed template file `Field Content: Images of property (ID: field_teamimage)` and after that you can add img src there, something like

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="team img 1" src="<?php print file_create_url($row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_teamimage['und'][0]['uri']); ?>"/>
```

You can even add image src directly in src.